# Faster saving method of bitmap C# wpf

Tags: c#, halcon

I'm currently working on machine vision project. The issue is saving all of the images fast enough so that the queue of images doesn't build up in RAM and drain the user's memory.  Is there any other method available for fast image saving?

This method helps the CPU issue, but because its not fast enough. The queue of images builds up and overloads the ram so I don't know what else I can do to solve both issues.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be related to WPF. What is ImageSaveInfo and HOperatorSet supposed to be?

Comment: `HOperatorSet` etc seems to be associated with a computer vision library called Halcon. I added a tag for that

Comment: How are the images generated / loaded? Maybe the answer is not to generate / load them as fast as is currently done?

Comment: But you dont keep the actual image in the queue just the filepath, wo why do you get out of memory´?

Comment: Also, you could probably farm out the saving by using a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-2.2), and spawn off multiple async tasks to dequeue and save the images. This should help utilise all your CPU and hopefully max out the hard-drive throughput.

Comment: @NPras yes it seems that an async / task design would be nicer. The method in the question obviously sits in a thread and "hammers" the queue to look for new images.

Comment: More like a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: I am voting to close, the OP has asked and run, and not clarifying any questions

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way for writing images in Halcon is using their proprietary format .hobj. It is much faster than any other lossless compression:

[image]

You can see the benchmark shown above in example `write_image_benchmark.hdev`

The only disadvantage is that you cannot open this format without the Halcon license.

Comment: Is there any other way to speed up the saving process instead of using Halcon library?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you are already using the Halcon library according to this line: HOperatorSet.WriteImage

Comment: yeah, the problem here is that it seems to be impractical as it required Halcon license to open the images.

Comment: i am looking a way to speed up saving all of the images fast enough so that the queue of images doesn't build up in RAM and drain the user's memory.

Comment: How often do you need to save the images and how many? Is it a machine where you have e.g. few seconds of intense image processing and then few seconds of pause? Can you describe the process a bit more?